# search_by_page search box will not submit the search for authenticated users

Tags: forms, theming, search

When an authenticated users searches the site using the search block from the [search_by_page](https://drupal.org/project/search_by_page) module the form does not have the needed `<input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-search-block-form-form-token" value="#####"  />` so the results can't be returned to the user. The following error message is shown:

**The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page.**

Where should I look to correct this bug? Is this a theming issue?

HTML from the search block:

```
<form class="search-by-page-form" action="/search-site" method="post" id="search-by-page-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" _lpchecked="1">
<div>
<div class="container">
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-keys">
<input type="text" id="edit-keys" name="keys" value="" size="30" maxlength="255" class="form-text typeMode">
</div>
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit--2" name="op" value="Search" class="form-submit">
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-#####-#####">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_by_page_form">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```